# How to remove BOM from SignalR responses at Mono server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, signalr, byte-order-mark

I am running signalR at Mono at all the requests are processed correctly, however the response always contains a byte at the beginning and the end of the file.

E.g. the response for hub.start() is this:

```
98
{"Url":"/signalr/signalr","ConnectionId":"785f2444-8320-4232-af54-793a7e0784e3","TryWebSockets":false,"WebSocketServerUrl":null,"ProtocolVersion":"1.0"}

0
```

Which of course cannot be parsed as JSON.

The same yields for the generated http://mysite.com/signalr/hubs script, it begins with this:

```
dce
/*!
 * ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v1.0.1
 * http://signalr.net/
```

And it breaks the browsers javascript parser.

The same issue does not occur when running under II, it occurs only at Mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your version of SignalR 0.5.3 is about 10 versions behind

Comment: I will try it, thanks. I must have been using a wrong nuget package, my bad.

Comment: The problem stil occurs even with the new version

Comment: There's no BOM in the new version. What version of SignalR are you using? https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/1.0.1

Comment: v1.0.1. I was mistaken that it was bom, it turned out to be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding and that can be fixed on the web server. Thanks for help.